# How to store values, protecting it against user modification?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm using this to to store a value:

```
localStorage.setItem('var', text);
```

And when the page is loaded, it do some action:

```
var text = getText(); //Get text from 'var' key.
localStorage.clear();
if (text!== null) {
    //Do some action
}
```

The problem is, the user can bypass the extension by adding manually, a value to the key 'var', is there any way that I can protect this data against user read and write?
If user manipulates this value, he will be able to have access to sensitive data.

Comment: You can't prevent users to access data located on their own computers.

Comment: What about protecting it against modification?

Comment: It's not possible either. Users can even change the code of your extension if they want. If you have sensitive data don't include it in your extension.

Comment: @rsanchez, thanks for your help, I'm making a extension for an third part site, I guess I have no option then, this variable was to save something temporarily and right after that process it, if the user couldn't change it it would work fine and safe. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @BernardoLima: Where is the sensitive data located ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, my extension works like so, it creates a textarea into a third part site, the users put a message on it and click a button, then it will add the message to localstorage, after the page reloads, it will check if there's any value at the localstorage, if so, it will add the message to my database. I don't want users trying to bypass it, adding values manually to localstorage, because then, my extension will add it anyways.

Comment: @BernardoLima: What's the difference ? They can input the value into the textarea anyway.

Comment: The problem is that as it uses the referrer page to get the user ID, people could fake the referrer, but you are right, is not a storage problem is an authentication problem, I guess there's no way around it, as the forum is a third part site, I'll never be able to authenticate users properly to assign them the text area text value.